# Abstract Algebra, homomorphism of rings, and equivalence classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations, ring-homomorphism

Let n be a positive integer. Define the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by $f(x) = [x]_n$. Prove that $f$ is a surjective homomorphism of rings.

So I know that in order to be a homomorphism of rings, we must show that 
$f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ and $f(ac) = f(a) f(c)$.

So I know that we must show that the equivalence classes

$[a]_n + [b]_n = f(a + b)$ and the same for multiplication, but I am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: *Hint:* $[x]_n + [y]_n=[x+y]_n, [x]_n\cdot [y]_n=[x \cdot y]_n$.

Comment: It may help to note that the operations on the equivalence classes in $Z/nZ$ are addition and multiplication modulo $n$.

Comment: @Krish can we assume this or is this something we can assume in the proof?

Comment: This is a standard fact from modular arithmatic. If you didn't prove it before, you *must* prove it now. In any case, if you assume this, then there is almost nothing to prove, isn't it? So it's my guess that it's better to include it in your proof also. (On the other hand, you can prove it as a separate claim, and then use it in your argument; in this way the proof won't be messy.)